# Rewriting part of url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rename the following urls

```
http://xyz.website.com/search/sOrder,dt_pub_date/iOrderType,desc
```

to

```
http://xyz.website.com/search/sOrder,dt_pub_date/iOrderType,desc/category,111
```

and

```
http://xyz.website.com/index.php?page=search<&item=1&city=2...and so on>
```

to

```
http://xyz.website.com/index.php?page=search&sCategory=111<&item=1&city=2...and so on>
```

Comment: Do those URLs contain literal commas and angled brackets?

Comment: they do contain commas, however angled brackets were for representation of a generic search string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first redirect, this an quick solution(if the query is static):

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(search/sOrder,dt_pub_date/iOrderType,desc).*$ /search/sOrder,dt_pub_date/iOrderType,desc/category,111
```

For the second one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=search(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?sCategory=111%1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this will helps you.